# Как вывести поля acf Repeater внутри другого acf Repeater?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть два разных повторителя (независимых репитера) и нужно одно поля из одного повторителя вывести в другой повторитель, как это сделать?
Или есть вариант записать поле из повторителя в массив - и выводить его в другом повторители.

Comment: Такое возможно сделать.

Comment: Это отлично - но как это сделать - может есть документация?

Comment: @NazarenkoRoman Ну так это шутка, у вас в вопросе просто сказано "такое возможно сделать" ну мы вам так и отвечаем, перепишите вопрос.

Comment: @NazarenkoRoman учточните, это репитер вложенный в репитер или это два независимых репитера на одной странице? Вопрос слишком общий. Как Вы и написали, Вы можете работать с повторителем, как с массивом и без проблем вывести нужные значения внутри второго повторителя, например.

Comment: Есть два разных повторителя - поправил описание

Comment: При помощи `get_field()` сохраните первый репитер в переменную, и работайте с его значениями как с массивом внутри второго, если со вторым вы используете `have_row()` и цикл `while`.  Пример есть в [документации](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/#foreach-loop), просто там это не внутри другого репитера, но принцип тот же.